# When I call another HTML page in a blank <div> it is shown in a small window instead of the full page

Tags: html

I have the home.html page where I have a menu. On clicking the link I want the addnew.html page to load into the    part of the code. I get the page but it is shown in an small section.....

**Home.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Contact Manager</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style1.css" />
<script>
function Load_addnew()
{
document.getElementById("load_here").innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="Addnew.html"></object>'
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="main">

<div id="logo">
<h1><center><a href="/" id="logo_">Contact Manager</a></center></h1>

</div>

<div id="menu">
<ul>
<li><a href="#" onclick="Load_addnew()">ADD NEW CONTACT</a></li>
<li><a href="">EDIT A CONTACT</a></li>
<li><a href="">DELETE CONTACT</a></li>
<li><a href="search.html">SEARCH CONTACTS</a></li>
<li><a href="">LIST OF CONTACTS</a></li>
</div>

<div id="load_here"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**Style1.css**

```
#main
{
background-repeat: repeat;
}
#logo a, #menu a
{
text-decoration: none;
}
#menu ul
{
line-height: 1.5em;
font-size: x-large;
float: left;
list-style: none;
}
#load_here
{
}
#logo
{
background-color: 
}
#menu
{
margin: 0px auto;
left: 0px;
right: 0px;
}
```

**AddNew.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Add Contact</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="addnew.css"></link>
</head>

<body>
<div id="main">

<ul id="errors">
<li id="info">Please recheck your form and Submit again: </li>
</ul>

<p id="success">Details Saved Successfully!!</p>

<div id="form1">
<form action="" method="" id="add_new">
<label for="Fname">First Name <span class="required">*</span>:</label>
<input type="text" id="First_Name" name="FirstName" value="" pattern="[A-Z a-z]" required="required" autofocus="autofocus"/>

<label for="Mname">Middle Name :</label>
<input type="text" id="Middle_Name" name="MiddleName" pattern="[A-Z a-z]" value=""/>

<label for="Lname">Last Name <span class="required">*</span>:</label>
<input type="text" id="Last_Name" name="LastName" value="" pattern="[A-Z a-z]" required="required"/>

<label for="dob">Date of Birth <span class="required">*</span>:</label>
<input type="date" id="DOB" name="dob" value="" required="required"/>

<label for="Phone1">Phone 1 <span class="required">*</span>:</label>
<input type="text" id="contactHome" name="Phone1" value="" required="required"/>

<label for="Phone2">Phone 2:</label>
<input type="text" id="contactOffice" name="Phone2" value=""/>

<label for="email">Email <span class="required">*</span>:</label>
<input type="email" id="email" name="Email" value="" placeholder="username@example.com" required="required"/>

<label for="Address">Address Line 1 <span class="required">*</span>:</label>
<input type="text" id="address" name="Address" required="required"/>

<label for="Address">Address Line 2:</label>
<input type="text" id="address1" name="Address1"/>

<label for="city">City <span class="required">*</span>:</label>
<input id="city" name="City" required="required" value=""/>

<label for="state">State <span class="required">*</span>:</label>
<input id="state" name="State" required="required" value=""/>

<label for="country">Country<span class="required">*</span>:</label>
<input id="country" name="Country" required="required" value=""/>

<label for="zip">PIN<span class="required">*</span>:</label>
<input id="zip" name="Zip" required="required" value=""/>

<input type="Submit" value="Submit" id="submit-button"/>
<input type="Reset" value="Reset" id="reset_button"/>

<p id="required-desc"><span class="required">*</span> indicates a required field</p>
</form>
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**addnew.css**

```
#main
{
width: 465px;
padding: 20px;
margin: 0px auto;
border: 6px solid #8fb5c1;
border-radius: 15px;
position: absolute;
background-repeat: repeat;
left: 0px;
right: 0px;
}
#main input, #main select, #main textarea, #main label
{
font-size: 15px;
margin-bottom: 2px;
}
#main input, #main select, #main textarea
{
width: 450px;
border: 1px solid #cee1e8;
margin-bottom: 20px;
padding: 4px;
}
#main input:focus, #main select:focus, #main textarea:focus
{
border: 1px solid #afcdd8;
background-color: #ebf2f4;
}
#main textarea
{
height: 80px;
resize: none;
}
#main label
{
display: block;
}
#main .required
{
font-weight: bold;
color: #f00;
}
#main #submit-button, #main #reset_button 
{
width: 100px;
background-color:#333;
color:#FFF;
border:none;
display:block;
float:right;
margin-bottom:0px;
margin-right:6px;
background-color:#8FB5C1;
} 
#main #submit-button:hover, #main #reset_button :hover
{
    background-color: #A6CFDD;
} 
#main #submit-button:active, #main #reset_button:active 
{
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
} 
#main #loading 
{
    width:32px;
    height:32px;
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    right:130px;
    bottom:16px;
    display:none;
}

#errors
{
border: solid 1px #e58e8e;
padding: 10px;
margin: block;
width: 437px;
border-radius: 8px;
background: #ffe6e6 no-repeat 405px center;
display: none;
}
#errors li
{
padding: 2px;
list-style: none;
}
#errors li:before
{
content: '-';
}
#errors #info 
{
font-weight: bold;
}
#errors #info:before 
{
content: '';   
}
#success 
{
border: solid 1px #83d186;
padding: 25px 10px;
margin: 25px 0px;
display: block;
width: 437px;
border-radius: 8px;
background: #d3edd3 no-repeat 405px center;
font-weight: bold;
display: none;
}
#errors.visible, #success.visible 
{
display: block;   
}
#form1 #req-field-desc 
{
font-style: italic;
}
```

Comment: Any reason you're embedding the html within an object tag? If it's by choice, you can style the object tag giving it a width/height.

Answer (score 0):

Easy enough if you set a `width` and `height`.

```
#load_here object
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
}
```

The problem you'll run into is that there is proportional sizing for this.  You'd have to specify both a `width` and a `height`, or it will default `width: 300px;` and `height: 150px;`.  So, if you set `width: 100%;` but don't set `height`, it'll render the height at `150px`, and vice versa.

I hope this helps. ^^